# Calculate the subtotal across Columns in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

Please find below my question.

My table

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8
ABC    1    1    4    5    2   1     1
CDE    1    1    1    1    1   1     1
```

Expected Output

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8  Subtotal
ABC    1    1    4    5    2   1     1      15
CDE    1    1    1    1    1   1     1       7
```

I am using oracle 10g.

I tried using the pivot function but it is not valid for oracle 10g.

Comment: this will help http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-12698.html

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a matter of adding the various columns together?

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8
       col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 + col6 + col7 + col8 subtotal
  FROM your_table
```

I'm guessing that there is more to the problem than your example conveys...

Comment: Thanks Justin foir the prompt reply.

I tried that but some values in the columns are nulls so it does not give a total for those rows.

Comment: @Prash you have to NVL the nullable columns like `nvl(col2, 0) + nvl(col3, 0) +...`

Comment: @Prash - OK.  If that's the case, it would help to include in your sample data a case where there are `NULL` values and tell us what you want the result to be.  Do you want to treat `NULL` values as 0, for example?  Or 1?  Or some other default?